# Understanding Spatial Frequency of Images (using matlab)

Tags: matlab, filters, frequency, image-processing, spatial

I wish to isolate a crosswalk from its surrounding, and I thought that as crosswalks have a repetitive pattern of thick white stripes, I might be able to isolate them by measuring their frequency range, and using a band pass filter with the right cut-off frequencies.

The problem is that I have no idea how to analyze the frequency of patterns in images. I know I should run fft2 on an isolated crosswalk, but I don't know what to do with the result.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the repetitive pattern, you may observe some strong magnitude at some position in frequency domain. Use `imagesc(abs(fftshift(fft2(img))))`, you probably would see:

[image]

Those small white spots in the image correspond to the repetitive texture that is superimposed on the image. You may then use `ordfilt2(F,roi^2,ones(roi))` to find out the `roi * roi` local maximum of the image. Here `F = abs(fftshift(fft2(img)))`, `roi` is the region size of interest. Then change those values to zero:

[image]

With the `real(ifft2(fftshift(F0)))` you will recover the image in spatial domain. F0 is the frequency distribution after you implement the white spots removal on  `fftshift(fft2(img)))`